# Do all pro-forms need to have antecedents?

Tags: deixis, pro-forms

Are all pro-forms the same in that they have to have antecedents and postcedents in the conversation to have any meaning? For example, the word "it" derives its meaning from a noun located either just before or just after the pronoun "it". Also, the word "Yes" is a pro-sentence, and it derives its meaning from a statement just said, for example, "Pizza is delicious." and then someone says "Yeah.". Would the person's "Yeah." mean "Yeah, pizza is delicious.", or is the meaning of a pro-form derived from something else?

Comment: Adding references would improve chances of an answer.

Comment: PRO or pro? A small, but important difference ;)

Comment: @lemontree, what is the difference between PRO and pro?

Comment: Yeah, @lemontree, I'd like to hear it, too. That distinction seems to posit more pluralities than necessity demands.

Comment: @jlawler & GDF1998 For German the difference is quite straightforward: While pro is semantically empty and does not affect the verb's valency, PRO will always fill an argument position of the verb. In general, PRO occurs in non-finite phrases, pro in finite ones. However, pro behaves differently across languages; in Italian pro can be referential (-> pro-drop), so I admit the difference is not always that obvious. But as long as there are languages in which there is a gramm. difference (at least German, also Dutch I think), I find it plausible to assume that there is pro and a distinct PRO.

Comment: However, reading through the question and the answers more closely, GFD1998 seems to refer to a different kind of pro than I was assuming (I was thinking of phonetically empty subjects, but this doesn't seem to make sense in this context), so my pointing out the difference might have been somewhat misplaced...

Comment: Thank you. There are several different ways to phonetically empty a subject; I spose big and little pro might set a flag in a derivation, but why bother? There's more than two varieties.

Answer (score 5):

yes and no. a proform by definition must refer to something else, but that "something else" need not be linguistic.  For example, Joe says something crazy.  I point my index finger to my temple and swirl it (meaning,  that's nutty).  Sally points at me and says "he's right" or "that's right" or similar.  I haven't *said* anything, but everybody understands Sally's point.

Comment: I am interested more with verbal and or written communication rather than nonverbal communication. Would someone have to say a referent in a conversation before using a pro-form for the pro-form to have any meaning whatsoever?

Comment: 'He is right' has no pro-form, and 'that is right' has a demonstrative, which isn't always considered a pro-form.  Weather 'it' (it is raining, it is late, it seems that ...) is a pro-form whose antecedent (a moment in time) need not be stated.

Comment: "He" is not a proform??? Please explain

Comment: @ami: "whether"?

Comment: So sorry; 'he' is definitely a pro-form (My glaucoma also blinds my brain sometimes).  'Weather it' refers to 'it' used as a reference to 'now'; it is not 'whether it'.

Comment: @GFD1998: Unequivocally no.  What's critical is a common understanding,  which can be implicit.  If I say "Fermat's last theorem is true", and you are a mathematician, you will understand me even though neither of us has explicitly articulated the theorem in *our* conversation.   Of course, somebody  (like Fermat) must have articulated it.

Comment: @ami: I don't understand what "Weather it" is supposed to mean.  It's not a sentence in my brand od English.

Comment: I guess you mean something like "I shall run the marathon tomorrow whether it is raining or not"?

Comment: NO!; I am sorry that the term 'weather it' is not common.  When 'it' refers to time or weather, then its antecedent is not a mentioned thing, but a moment in time.  "It is raining." (no antecedent) vs "I saw a bird.  It fell." (antecedent of 'it' is the bird)

Comment: Ok, you mean " 'it', when used to refer to weather, is a pro-form...etc."?  If so, I agree that that is an example of use of a proform without an explicitly articulated antecedent.  But that is exactly my point: there *is* a shared, antecedent context (namely the weather, right now), without which the utterance would be completely opaque.

Answer (score 0):

Brainstorming a bit turns up a lot of examples, it seems. Sometimes it will boil down to definition (are demonstratives pro-forms), but even excluding demonstratives, I can think of quite a lot:

> (1) Generic pronouns:
>
> ```
>  *On*     ne  sait pas.
>  *3sg.*   NEG know NEG. (French)
>  *One* does not know / We can't tell
> ```
>
> (2) Speech act participants: **I**'m a little teaport, short and stout.
>
> (2) Reflexives in nominalised VPs:
>
> ```
> 不  患    人      之  不  *己* 知
> Bu  huan  ren    zhi bu  *ji*     zhi
> NEG worry others GEN NEG *self*   know (Old Chinese)
> Do not worry about others' not knowing the *self*
> ```
>
> (3) Reciprocals in nominalised VPs: Knowing **each other** well is important for teamwork.
>
> (4) Pro-sentences in polar questions:
>
> ```
> Ana    ruwa, *ko*?
> one.is rain  *or*
> Is it raining or **not**? (Hausa - Schachter and Shopen 2007)
> ```
>
> (5) Answers to questions: The original sentence in the OP if it came from this conversation:
>
> ```
> A: Is pizza delicious?
> B: *No*!
> ```
>
> Since the statement 'Pizza is not delicious' never appeared in the conversation.

References:

Schachter, P. and Shopen, T. (2007). Parts of speech. In Shopen, T. (ed.), *Language typology and syntactic description* (Vol. 3). Cambridge: Cambridge University Press.

Answer (score -1):

Most pro-forms will denote things which are more explicitly discussed in the conversation, but some do not.

One example is the English word *now*, which (IMO) [should be analysed as a pro-preposition](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/298405/59258). *Now* stands in for a temporal phrase, such as *at this moment in time*, but only rarely would a speaker also refer to that moment with a full prepositional phrase.

Comment: Note the equivalence of 'now' and weather 'it'.